# App to play audio for 5s then pause for 10-15s automatically

Tags: media-player, audio-player

Recently I started to learn English and one of my practices is to transcript audio. So I’m looking for an app to play audio for 5s then pause for 10-15s and so on until the end of the audio. Any suggestions?
I have Windows and Mac computers, and also an iPad if there is any app in the App Store.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! So you're looking for an app to run on apple devices – or primarily on Android?

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a guide that may be of help. The app that comes to mind is [MPV](https://mpv.io/) - a command line player. It has pause, restart, timer features. So you could probably ask in the [issues queue](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/issues) if there is a quick way or script to do this.